# While loop displaying correct answer as incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the while loop is supposed to make the user enter one of the two available choices (y/n) but if i input anything, it is shown as incorrect.

I have tried changing the ! to a = and some other minute things but that has done nothing.

```py
print("Hello there " + str(name) + ", are you ready for your 
adventure? Y/N")
    adventure = input()
    while adventure.lower() != "y" or "n":
        print(str(name) + " ,that's not a choice. I'll ask again, are 
you ready for your adventure? Y/N")
        adventure = input()
    if adventure.lower() == "n":
        print("Cowards take the way out quickly.")
        breakpoint
    else:
        print("Come, you will make a fine explorer for the empire!")
```

It isn't a syntax error but it is a logic error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: I realized I should have asked for clarification first before voting. You mean it refuses to stop looping regardless of what  input you enter?

Comment: @Carcigenicate , yes no matter what variable i put in, it just displays the same code:,                                that's not a choice. I'll ask again, are 
you ready for your adventure? Y/N")

Comment: See the post I linked to. You can't compare `adventure` against multiple strings by putting `or "n":` at the end. You need to write it out fully `adventure.lower() != "y" and adventure.lower() != "n"`, or use a more advanced method like using a set. You also need to use `and`, not `or`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate , i didn't know about that. I have done this technique before a few times. BTW, after adding what you said, the code still isn't working.

Comment: If you used it before, it only seemed to work; it didn't actually do what you wanted. `... or "n"` will always be true, no matter what `...` is. That's why it's important to test your code thoroughly.

Comment: @Carcigenicate would you mind writing it out for me cos now im a bit confused

Comment: Note the code I included in my second comment. The linked post also goes into great detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if statement to:

```
print("Hello there " + str(name) + ", are you ready for your 
adventure? Y/N")
adventure = input()
while adventure.lower() not in ("y", "n"): # <<<<<---- This line changed

    print(str(name) + " ,that's not a choice. I'll ask again, are 
you ready for your adventure? Y/N")
    adventure = input()
    if adventure.lower() == "n":
        print("Cowards take the way out quickly.")
        breakpoint
    else:
        print("Come, you will make a fine explorer for the empire!")
```

This is due to how comparisons are done in Python3. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149/5763413)

Some other fixes you can make to your code:

```
adventure = input("Hello there {}, are you ready for your adventure? Y/N".format(name)) #Added prompt to input, using string formatting. 

while adventure.lower() not in ("y", "n"): # <<<<<---- Check input against tuple, instead of using `or` statement

    adventure = input(" {}, that's not a choice. I'll ask again, are you ready for your adventure? Y/N".format(name)) #Same as first line
    if adventure.lower() == "n":
        print("Cowards take the way out quickly.")
        break
    else:
        print("Come, you will make a fine explorer for the empire!")
```

See [usage of python input command](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp), [string formatting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3)

Comment: Cheers dude. Thank you so much  BTW, do you reccoment the not in ("x", "y") rather than the way i did it?

Comment: Thanks! If it worked, please consider marking this answer as "Accepted".

Comment: Yes, if you look at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149/5763413), you can read about why this happens. It's due to something called "operator precedence".

Comment: Yup! That's it. Glad I could help.

Comment: In most cases it would be better to use a set instead of a tuple as in: {"y", "n"}

Comment: @MikeSperry why is that? Not questioning you, I just like to learn.